# useFetch in onMounted not fetching data on direct link open nuxt3

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3

I'm using the `useFetch` to fetch the data in the composition api and then calling the function in `onMounted` hook in components, here is the code.

**useShows.ts** (composable)

```
export function useShows(){

    var shows = useState<Show[]>('shows')

    const fetchShows = async() => {
        const {data, pending} = await useFetch<Show[]>('http://localhost:3000/shows')
        shows.value = data.value
    }

    return {shows, fetchShows}
}
```

**shows.vue**

```
<script setup lang="ts">

    var { shows, fetchShows } = useShows()

    onMounted(() => {
        console.log("On mounted called")
        fetchShows()
    })
</script>

<template>
    <div>{{shows}}</div>
</template>
```

When I'm navigating to `/shows` from the home page it is working fine, but when I direct open the link `localhost/shows` it is not working and only giving me the null.

Answer (score 8):

I have the exact same problem. I solved it by wrapping it within a nextTick.

```
await nextTick(async () => {
  await fetchShows()
})
```

Comment: Can you explain the reason?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know as well. Looking for an answer as well.